# Building styling in an Azure DevOps extension

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, azure-devops-extensions

My extension does not contain any css files when I build it and I don't know what makes it do that. I did not change the `Common.tsx` that was scaffolded. Neither my own styles or the Azure DevOps UI styling gets packaged or used by components.

Azure DevOps UI documentation says to do this:

> https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-devops/develop/extensions
>
> When consuming the 2.164.0 version or later of the azure-devops-ui package, extensions should import the Azure DevOps global styles in order to get the same look and feel (font family, font sizes, hyperlink treatment, etc.) of Azure DevOps pages. This can be done with the following import:
>
> `import "azure-devops-ui/Core/override.css";`

This is already done in the `Common.tsx` by default however.

**directory structure**

```
src
│   Common.scss
│   Common.tsx
│
└───Components
    └───RESTRequestButton
            RESTRequestButton.html
            RESTRequestButton.json
            RESTRequestButton.scss
            RESTRequestButton.tsx
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

const entries = {};

const ComponentsDir = path.join(__dirname, "src/Components");
fs.readdirSync(ComponentsDir).filter(dir => {
    if (fs.statSync(path.join(ComponentsDir, dir)).isDirectory()) {
        entries[dir] = "./" + path.relative(process.cwd(), path.join(ComponentsDir, dir, dir));
    }
});

module.exports = {
    entry: entries,
    output: {
        filename: "[name]/[name].js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
        alias: {
            "azure-devops-extension-sdk": path.resolve("node_modules/azure-devops-extension-sdk")
        },
    },
    stats: {
        warnings: false
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss?$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "azure-devops-ui/buildScripts/css-variables-loader", "sass-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css?$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff?$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'base64-inline-loader'
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html?$/,
                loader: "file-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
           patterns: [ 
               { from: "**/*.html", context: "src/Components" }
           ]
        })
    ]
};
```

**Common.tsx**

```js
import "azure-devops-ui/Core/override.css";
import "es6-promise/auto";
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./Common.scss";

export function showRootComponent(component: React.ReactElement<any>) {
    ReactDOM.render(component, document.getElementById("root"));
}
```

**RESTRequestButton.scss**

```scss
@import "node_modules/azure-devops-ui/Core/_platformCommon.scss";
```

**RESTRequestButton.tsx (only how I import the styling and how I reference Common.tsx)**

```js
import "./RestRequestButton.scss";
import { showRootComponent } from "../../Common";

class RESTRequestButton extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    //a lot of code goes here
}

export default RESTRequestButton;
showRootComponent(<RESTRequestButton />);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to bump package versions. I set package `style-loader` to `"^3.3.1"` and it was fixed.

Comment: Hi, Apodemus, thanks for your feedback and kindly sharing. To benefit more developers and users, you could highlight this solution to help them with the similar scenario.

Comment: I couldn't accept my own answer on the same day the question was posted, but it should be possible in 3 hours.